# Object passed to function becomes undefined

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
handler: {},

init: function () {
    this.handler['Bonus'] = this.handleBonus();
},

handleReplica: function (msg) {
    var gameObjects = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    var survivors = new Set();
    for (var i = 0; i < gameObjects.length; i++) {
        var obj = gameObjects[i];
        console.log(obj);

        if (gMessages.handler[obj.type] === undefined)
            continue;

        survivors.add(obj.id);
        gMessages.handler[obj.type](obj);
    }
    gGameEngine.gc(survivors);
},

handleBonus: function(obj) {
    var bonus = gGameEngine.bonuses.find(function (el) {
        return el.id === obj.id;
    });
    var position = Utils.getEntityPosition(obj.position);

    if (bonus) {
        bonus.bmp.x = position.x;
        bonus.bmp.y = position.y;
    } else {
        bonus = new Bonus(obj.id, position, obj.bonusType);
        gGameEngine.bonuses.push(bonus);
    }
}
```

I've left only parts where I have a problem. And here it is: `obj` is undefined in `handleBonus` (Cannot read property 'position' of undefined). How could it be if I'm passing it like this: `gMessages.handler[obj.type](obj);` Obviously, here obj is defined.

Comment: When you set the handler, you set it not to the function, but to its return value.  You're _calling_ `this.HandleBonus()` instead of referring to `this.HandleBonus`.  and when you call it, you don't provide obj.  Maybe just taking off the `()` would be the first thing to try?

Comment: Ohhhh, it looks like it's time for me to sleep... Post the answer if you want to, I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the handler, you set it not to the function, but to its return value. You're calling this.HandleBonus() instead of referring to this.HandleBonus. and when you call it, you don't provide obj. Maybe just taking off the () would be the first thing to try?